# Rows to dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have some data in the following format

```
[[Row(database_description_item='Catalog Name', database_description_value='spark_catalog'),
  Row(database_description_item='Namespace Name', database_description_value='dummydb'),
  Row(database_description_item='Comment', database_description_value=''),
  Row(database_description_item='Location', database_description_value='physical/location/of/database/'),
  Row(database_description_item='Owner', database_description_value='username')],
 [Row(database_description_item='Catalog Name', database_description_value='spark_catalog'),
  Row(database_description_item='Namespace Name', database_description_value='dummydb2'),
  Row(database_description_item='Comment', database_description_value=''),
  Row(database_description_item='Location', database_description_value='physical/location/of/database/'),
  Row(database_description_item='Owner', database_description_value='username')],
 [Row(database_description_item='Catalog Name', database_description_value='spark_catalog'),
  Row(database_description_item='Namespace Name', database_description_value='dummydb3'),
  Row(database_description_item='Comment', database_description_value='some description here'),
  Row(database_description_item='Location', database_description_value='physical/location/of/database/'),
  Row(database_description_item='Owner', database_description_value='username')]
```

I want to convert it into a dataframe with columns names essentially as below:

```
Catalog_name,Namespace_Name,Comment,Location,Owner
```

the output i want should be something like below

[image]

I have tried a few ways to convert these rows but couldn't figure out how to

The code i have tried is as below

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rows=[]
for r in l:
  row = Row(r)
  rows.append(row)
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows)
df = rdd.toDF().toPandas()
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df['_1'].to_list(), columns=['Catalog_Name','Namespace_Name','Comment','Location','Owner'])
```

the above gives an output with each cell containing a list.
any help please.

Comment: What is `l`? Why are you using `Row` initializer if you need a dataframe? Maybe it's better to append straight to a dr in the loop?

Comment: i was  just trying a few solutions.. can you please provide the code to do that. L is a list created in a previous step and the output in L is the one given above.

Comment: Do you need Pyspark dataframe or Pandas dataframe?  Also, please show the `l`, to create either dataframe, you don't have to convert it to `Row`.